# make visible div on dropdown select in jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am developing the asp.net mvc application . my one of forms requirement is that:
It has dropdown filling up with let say A,B,C values. If selected A then on UI there should be 2 text boxes should be visible and other should be invisible , if selected B, then must be add another 2 text boxes , i this way there should be 4 text boxes. same for 
selection of C. 
I able to get the selected value by

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#NatureOfTransactionDropDown').change(function() {

        var element = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text();
        alert(element);
        if (element == "A") {
           //code
          }
    });
});
```

What I have to do. I tried hide() show(), but i think it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.css("display", "none");` for hiding, 
and `.css("display", "block");` for showing

Comment: yes, +1 , but after I select any value in drop down ,it is not posting back . how to manage this in the asp.net mvc

Comment: just add submit() javascript function to post the form. document.forms["myform"].submit();

Comment: ok, but then I have ViewData on my view page. so I need to get its value and need to set again manually , right ? I am able to get value of ViewData. but how can i set value back to ViewData ?

Comment: I have done, no need to do we discussed things. Script is         function makeInternalRuleVisible() {

            $('#divLease').hide();

            var element = $('#NatureOfTransactionId').find('option').filter(':selected').text();
        
            if (element == "A") {
              
                $('#divLease').show();

            }
            else {
                $('#divLease').hide();

            }
        }