# I need to change Multiview or place holder whenever I select different values in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating online booking page.

I got some example page you can see in this link
http://www.parkercorporate.co.uk/webbookercc/OneForm.asp

I need the same behaviour in my site whenever user selects value in pickup dropdown list in the right side I need to change the text values or view.

To do this behaviour how should I write code in ASP.NET and c#.

Thanks
Ranam

Answer (score 0):

First, use an UpdatePanel so you don't see any visual postback.
Second, set the AutoPostBack property on your DropDownList to True.
Third, handle the DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event. This will now fire after every change in the DropDownList, because you enabled AutoPostBack.

In the event handler, you can now change the ActiveViewIndex of the MultiView, or show/hide controls, change textboxes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, create different blocks (i.e divs) and give ID's to them. 
Then, for each value in the dropbox, fill the divs w.r.t it.

Assign "OnChange" event to the dropdown, and in the handler, set visible or invisible to corresponding block.

On the other hand, If you want to do this on client side, I strongly suggest you to use JQuery, to prevent a lot of requests going to server.

Check this out with JQuery:
[make visible div on dropdown select in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274892/make-visible-div-on-dropdown-select-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you won't fetch values from database, there is nothing complex about this page. Because it just writes hospital if you choose hospital etc. and changes control's visible state.

Even if you think you need db queries when dropdown's selected change event, actually at this page there is no need. Just store db values in hidden controls (like Hospital- for Hospital) and when dropdown selection changes, write hidden's value completely in javascript